# Genetic algorithm for Clever Algorithms project

Tags: ruby, genetic-algorithm

I wrote a bunch of Ruby code for a book project I've just finished. One criticism is that it is fine code but not very "ruby like". I agree my style was simplified for communication reasons, and although it's procedural code, it still feels "ruby-like" to me.

For the representative example below, any ideas on making it more "Ruby like"?

```
# Genetic Algorithm in the Ruby Programming Language

# The Clever Algorithms Project: http://www.CleverAlgorithms.com
# (c) Copyright 2010 Jason Brownlee. Some Rights Reserved. 
# This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 2.5 Australia License.

def onemax(bitstring)
  sum = 0
  bitstring.size.times {|i| sum+=1 if bitstring[i].chr=='1'}
  return sum
end

def random_bitstring(num_bits)
  return (0...num_bits).inject(""){|s,i| s<<((rand<0.5) ? "1" : "0")}
end

def binary_tournament(pop)
  i, j = rand(pop.size), rand(pop.size)
  j = rand(pop.size) while j==i
  return (pop[i][:fitness] > pop[j][:fitness]) ? pop[i] : pop[j]
end

def point_mutation(bitstring, rate=1.0/bitstring.size)
  child = ""
   bitstring.size.times do |i|
     bit = bitstring[i].chr
     child << ((rand()<rate) ? ((bit=='1') ? "0" : "1") : bit)
  end
  return child
end

def crossover(parent1, parent2, rate)
  return ""+parent1 if rand()>=rate
  point = 1 + rand(parent1.size-2)
  return parent1[0...point]+parent2[point...(parent1.size)]
end

def reproduce(selected, pop_size, p_cross, p_mutation)
  children = []  
  selected.each_with_index do |p1, i|
    p2 = (i.modulo(2)==0) ? selected[i+1] : selected[i-1]
    p2 = selected[0] if i == selected.size-1
    child = {}
    child[:bitstring] = crossover(p1[:bitstring], p2[:bitstring], p_cross)
    child[:bitstring] = point_mutation(child[:bitstring], p_mutation)
    children << child
    break if children.size >= pop_size
  end
  return children
end

def search(max_gens, num_bits, pop_size, p_crossover, p_mutation)
  population = Array.new(pop_size) do |i|
    {:bitstring=>random_bitstring(num_bits)}
  end
  population.each{|c| c[:fitness] = onemax(c[:bitstring])}
  best = population.sort{|x,y| y[:fitness] <=> x[:fitness]}.first  
  max_gens.times do |gen|
    selected = Array.new(pop_size){|i| binary_tournament(population)}
    children = reproduce(selected, pop_size, p_crossover, p_mutation)    
    children.each{|c| c[:fitness] = onemax(c[:bitstring])}
    children.sort!{|x,y| y[:fitness] <=> x[:fitness]}
    best = children.first if children.first[:fitness] >= best[:fitness]
    population = children
    puts " > gen #{gen}, best: #{best[:fitness]}, #{best[:bitstring]}"
    break if best[:fitness] == num_bits
  end
  return best
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  # problem configuration
  num_bits = 64
  # algorithm configuration
  max_gens = 100
  pop_size = 100
  p_crossover = 0.98
  p_mutation = 1.0/num_bits
  # execute the algorithm
  best = search(max_gens, num_bits, pop_size, p_crossover, p_mutation)
  puts "done! Solution: f=#{best[:fitness]}, s=#{best[:bitstring]}"
end
```

Comment: Looked at your book, algorithm-wise - good explanations. but you should've asked a rubyist to take a look at the code before it got published :(

Comment: I'm just agreeing all over the place with you glebm. It's a bit insulting really. Like if I wrote a book on Middle East politics and US foreign policy but didn't bother to consult with experts on the matter. Oh well, at least the book is free in PDF form.

Comment: It is time for the second edition.

Comment: Please format your code using the code button in the format bar, not pre-tags. The way it is now, some of the code won't display because of `<` and `>` characters in it.

Comment: Agreed, I should have got more ruby people to look at the book before I published it. I simply ran out of time, and in your eyes, it makes the work less professional. To be fair, it is not a ruby book, it is an AI book. From this perspective, the use of rubyisms is important but should be metered by the requirements of good communication (ability for non-ruby people to parse and port to their preferred language). The book is on github, I'd love to see a ruby-purist version of the sample code!!!! In fact, I'd really love to link to a "jason" and "purist" versions of each algorithm on the web.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First a note on your general design: You use hashmaps to represent members of the population. I'd rather recommend you create a little class to represent them:

```
class Individual
  include Comparable

  attr_reader :bitstring, :fitness

  def initialize(bitstring)
    @bit_string = bitstring
    @fitness = onemax(bitstring)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    fitness <=> other.fitness
  end
end
```

You'll now use `Individual.new(bitstring)` to create a new individual (which will automatically calculate its own fittness) and `individual.bitstring` and `individual.fitness` to get an individual's bitstring or fitness respectively.

This has the benefit that now the logic of how to calculate an individuals fitness lives in the `Individual` class instead of in multiple place in the `search` method. This is a more natural place for it and makes it easier to find and change should you ever decide to use a different fitness function.

Also note that I included Comparable, implementing `<=>` based on fitness. This means that you can now compare individuals to each other such that an individual is greater than another if and only if its fitness is greater. This allows you to use `>` on two individuals as well as methods like `max` to get the individual with the greatest fitness out of an array of individuals. It also allows you to call `sort` on array of individuals without passing a block. This will simplify your code in some places.

---

In a comment you mentioned that you don't want to use classes. However I still think that it would greatly improve your design to have the logic for creating new individuals and calculating their fitness in one single place, so you should at least factor it out into a method like this:

```
def create_individual(bitstring)
    {:bitstring => bitstring, :fitness => onemax(bitstring)}
end
```

---

Now some notes on particular pieces of code:

```
bitstring.size.times {|i| sum+=1 if bitstring[i].chr=='1'}
```

As has already been mentioned, this can easily be replaced with a call to `count`. However as a general note I want to point out that it's good practice to avoid index-based loops wherever possible, so if `count` did not exist, I'd write the above like this:

```
bitstring.each_char {|c| sum+=1 if c == '1'}
```

Or for 1.8.6 compability:

```
bitstring.each_byte {|b| sum+=1 if b.chr == '1'}
```

---

```
(0...num_bits).inject(""){|s,i| s<<((rand<0.5) ? "1" : "0")}
```

When dealing with `inject`, it's usually a good idea to keep the function simple, so it's more easily understandable. Often you can separate the logic of generating the elements from the logic of combining them, by using `map` before `inject`. This would make your code look like this:

```
(0...num_bits).map {|i| (rand<0.5) ? "1" : "0"}.inject("") {|s,i| s<<i}
```

Now there's two things to notice here:

1. Whenever you call `map` on a range from 0 to some size, you might rather want to use `Array.new(size) {block}` which creates an array of the given size by calling the block `size` times.
2. The smaller `inject` is now much easier to understand, but happens to be equivalent to calling `join`, so let's just do that.

So your code becomes:

```
Array.new(num_bits) { (rand<0.5) ? "1" : "0" }.join
```

This way you create a temporary array, which you didn't before, but on the other hand your code became much more understandable, so that little inefficiency should be worth it.

---

```
(pop[i][:fitness] > pop[j][:fitness]) ? pop[i] : pop[j]
```

Thanks to the `Individual` class this now looks like this:

```
(pop[i] > pop[j]) ? pop[i] : pop[j]
```

This isn't much different, but note that it now has the form `(x > y) ? x : y`, which incidentally means "the maximum of two objects". In other words we can simplify this code by using the `max` method:

```
[ pop[i], pop[j] ].max
```

---

```
bitstring.size.times do |i|
  bit = bitstring[i].chr
```

Again this should be `bitstring.each_char do |bit|` or `bitstring.each_byte do |b| bit = b.chr`.

---

```
""+parent1 if rand()>=rate
```

<s>I'm not sure what the `""+` is supposed to do here. Remove it. Note that `""+x` is not a way to turn `x` into a string in ruby (like it would be in e.g. Java). Calling `""+x` when `x` is not a string (or "duck-string"), will cause a type error.</s>

The fact that you're using `""+` to create a copy is less than obvious (thus the above paragraph). If you use the `dup` method, whose sole purpose it is to create a copy, instead, it will be much more understandable.

---

I'd also change the `crossover` method to return an individual rather than a string, which makes the code a bit simpler.

Comment: Some great suggestions, thank-you for taking the time. I especially love the random bitstring suggestion. Regarding the use of the object, I explicitly chose a procedural paradigm for presentation although agree having objects can make the organization of the code much better. I had to drop each_char (and a few other funcs) for 1.8.6 support. The ""+parent1 was to make a quick copy of the string object (overly cautious, i know). Thanks again!

Comment: @jasonb: If you can't use `each_char`, use `each_byte` at least (it will be the same except that you get an integer, which you need to call `chr` on). That's still better than iterating over the indices. To create a copy of an object, you should use `dup`, which makes it clear to the reader what you're doing.

Comment: @jasonb: Even for procedural code it's still bad design to have the fitness code in several places inside the `search` method. If you don't want to use classes, I'd at least recommend a `create_individual` method which takes a bitstring and returns a hash with the bitstring and the fitness. This way the fitness calculation still takes place in a single location.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby library is quite powerful:

`onemax(bitstring)` can be simply `bitstring.count('1')`

`random_bitstring(num_bits)` is probably better off implemented as `rand(2**num_bits).to_s(2)`

The first thing to check out is this http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the count method - your onemax is excellent. I really do need to read the API more. The suggestion for random_bitstring, although elegant, I find difficult to parse. Granted mine is worse, but I feel like that a non-ruby person could figure out my version from reading a "quick start language guide", yours would require the API open in another tab. I am finding this case far less clear cut. Thanks again for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

An easy one is to remove the `return` at the end of each method. Ruby automatically does a return of the last value. It's actually an extra method call to use `return`.

<strike>The only time you specifically need to use return is</strike> You don't even need to use return if you are returning multiple values:

```
def f
  [1,2]
end

a,b = f
```

Again, using `return` costs an extra method call and those add up. If you can optimize your code by not using them you've just given yourself some free optimization.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In this case, I think it would only apply to the "onemax", "random_bitstring", and "point_mutation" functions.

Comment: No remove it on EVERY function. For instance in the `reproduce` method change the last line from `return children` to just `children`. The only time you need to use return in Ruby is if you are returning multiple values, e.g. `def f() return 1,2 end  a,b = f()`

Comment: better return multiple values like this: `def f() [1, 2] end`

Comment: @glebm Agreed, I stand corrected. Return isn't even needed with multiple return values.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently going through the book and yes, as admitted it's not the most Ruby-esque code I've ever seen, but I think it does achieve the main objectives of what it was set out to accomplish and I don't think the Ruby gets in the way of that.

The thing I've noticed most when trying to following along, run, and even augment some of the methods was the general flow. There's a few things I can't say "YOU SHOULD DO IT THIS WAY THUS SAYETH THE RUBY" but it would just "feel" more comfortable if:

- The configurations were done at the beginning of the file in a Hash. As far as using a Hash, you see Hash configs a lot in Ruby, many times due to the use and reading of .yml config files so I guess I just expect configs to be done in a Hash. (If this were an application, I'd say put the configs in a .yml file, but I understand the desire to have the full solution encapsulated in a single file.)
- The "search" method definition were at the beginning of the file, right under a Hash outlining the config. (The calling of the search method still happens at the bottom in your if **FILE** section.)

Ok so the at the beginning thing is definitely debatable, but I just found myself dropping in to each of these files, scrolling to the bottom, reading the config, scrolling up a little and reading the "search" method to get a high level view of what's going on, then scrolling to the top again to dig into the supporting methods.

Another debatable style I've enjoyed in both reading and writing Ruby is using a space to pad the beginning and end of an inline block.

So

```
children.sort!{|x,y| y[:fitness] <=> x[:fitness]}
```

becomes

```
children.sort!{ |x,y| y[:fitness] <=> x[:fitness] }
```

Yeah it's a small thing and some people will say anything that adds extra keystrokes to typing is bad, but I find it much more readable.

Also just now noticing some inconsistent spacing when using operators...and as you can probably guess, I vote for more spacing in most situations. ;)

```
def crossover(parent1, parent2, rate)
  return ""+parent1 if rand()>=rate
  point = 1 + rand(parent1.size-2)
  return parent1[0...point]+parent2[point...(parent1.size)]
end
```

becomes

```
def crossover(parent1, parent2, rate)
  return "" + parent1 if rand() >= rate
  point = 1 + rand(parent1.size-2)
  return parent1[0...point] + parent2[point...(parent1.size)]
end
```

And now I'm getting nit picky...so I'm done for now.