# Make Project Euler 27 solution idiomatic Ruby

Tags: ruby, primes, mathematics, programming-challenge

I learned to program in Java and C# and in my free time I am using Ruby because it is fun. Unfortunately I have the feeling that I write Ruby code like I am making Java or C# code. I have learned to use regex instead of strings for comparison, using each instead of for-loops, keeping method names lowercase, and how to use code blocks (which are quite similar to lambda expressions in C#).

I would love to improve the Rubiness of my code and I hope you would be willing to give me one or more pointers on a piece of code I made. It answers [Project Euler problem 27](http://projecteuler.net/problem=27).

```
class Integer
  def prime?
    return false if self < 1
    2.upto(Math.sqrt(self)) do |i|
      return false if self % i == 0
    end
    true
  end
end

def get_amount_of_primes_from_quadratic_formula(a,b)
  primes = []
  still_all_primes = true
  n = 0
  while still_all_primes
    result = n**2 + a*n + b
    if result.prime? then
      primes << result
    else
      still_all_primes = false
    end
    n += 1
  end
  primes.size
end

def get_product_of_coefficients_that_produce_maximum_number_of_primes_for_consecutive_values()
  max_product = 0
  max_primes = 0
  -999.upto(1000) do |a|
    -999.upto(1000) do |b|
      primes = get_amount_of_primes_from_quadratic_formula(a,b)
      if primes > max_primes then
        max_primes = primes
        max_product = a*b
      end
    end
  end
  max_product
end

start = Time.now
answer = get_product_of_coefficients_that_produce_maximum_number_of_primes_for_consecutive_values()

puts "The answer is #{answer} and it took #{Time.now-start} seconds."
```

I think I can improve on the if-then statement and write it more concise, and also the two "upto-loops" where I first declare the variables `max_primes` and `max_product` can be written in a more Ruby-way I am sure.

I would be very grateful if you could let me know how to write more like Ruby!

Links that ask similar questions which I am reading in the meantime:

- [Advice on making ruby code more ruby-like](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/354/advice-on-making-ruby-code-more-ruby-like)
- [Ruby method return values - how to be more Ruby-like?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16378/ruby-method-return-values-how-to-be-more-ruby-like)
- [How to make my script nicer / more Ruby?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15413/how-to-make-my-script-nicer-more-ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Succinctness**
As rubyists, we love being succinct, and we love playing with enumerations.

You will see very few literal `false` and `true` in ruby code, as well as very few explicit `return` calls.

For example:

Instead of writing `return false if self < 1` we will prefer to compound the condition to `self >= 1 && ...` which will do the same thing, but we "save" `return false`.

**The power of Enumeration**
Ruby has a very powerful [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html), and is used widely, often more than once in a line (using method chaining).

For example:

> ```
> 2.upto(Math.sqrt(self)) do |i|
>   return false if self % i == 0
> end
> ```

Here you check if any of the numbers in the range are a divisor for `self`, and break if there is any. A more ruby way of doing it will be:

```
return false if 2.upto(Math.sqrt(self)).any? { |i| self % i == 0 }
```

We'll also prefer to more succinct range syntax `(2..Math.sqrt(self))`, which is simply shorter...

So now, our `def prime?` method could be reduced to a one-liner:

```
class Integer
  def prime?
    self > 1 && !(2..Math.sqrt(self)).any? { |i| self % i == 0 }
  end
end
```

**Mapping**
Anywhere in the code I see the following pattern:

```
result = []
some_loop do
  result << something
end
```

A red flag is raised, and I look for a way to use `map` to do the same thing:

```
result = some_loop.map { something }
```

Your code goes over all the non-negative integers, and takes counts how many of them result in a prime, until the first non-prime.

"All the non-negative integers" can be expressed in ruby as `(0..Float::INFINITY)`, so we can write:

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).map { |n| n**2 + a*n + b }.take_while { |result| result.prime? }.count
```

This code takes each integer, *maps* it into the result of `n**2 + a*n + b`, takes all the results until they are no longer prime, and counts how many are there.

Cool! Right? The only problem with the code above, is that it will take infinity to complete it, as it takes *all* the numbers and maps them, and *then* checks for how many to take.

To solve this problem ruby now has...

**Lazy Enumerables**
As of ruby 2.0, [lazy enumerables](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/) allows you to calculate values in an infinite stream only as needed.

To solve the problem above, all we need to do now is to add the `lazy` operator on the range:

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map { |n| n**2 + a*n + b }.take_while(&:prime?).count
```

And we have another one-liner!

**Everything is an enumerable**
So you want to save on your "upto-loops"? Let's do it!

You want to enumerate over each pair of numbers from `-999` to `1000`, so what you actually want is to have a long matrix of those pairs:

```
[[-999, -999], [-999, -998],...,[1000, 1000]].do_something_smart
```

To do that, you can use [`product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
(-999..1000).to_a.product((-999..1000).to_a)
```

But since both `a` and `b` have the same range, we can even DRY this up, and use [`repeated_permutation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
(-999..1000).to_a.repeated_permutation(2)
```

Both of these solutions will give you the needed matrix, so we can move on the see what we should do with it...

We want to get the coeffiecients that produce the number of primes, so let's do just that:

```
a, b = (-999..1000).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).max_by { |a, b| get_amount_of_primes_from_quadratic_formula(a,b) }
```

Now all we need to do is multiply them with each other!

**Method naming**
Your names are very verbose, which is a good thing, but ruby idiom frowns upon `get_` prefixes. Also, prefer using verbs already in the language (`count`) over those which are not in the language (`amount_of`)

So now the code will look like:

```
class Integer
  def prime?
    self > 1 && !(2..Math.sqrt(self)).any? { |i| self % i == 0 }
  end
end

def count_quadratic_formula_primes(a,b)
  (0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map { |n| n**2 + a*n + b }.take_while(&:prime?).count
end

def product_of_coefficients_that_produce_maximum_number_of_primes_for_consecutive_values()
  a, b = (-999..1000).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).max_by { |a, b| count_quadratic_formula_primes(a,b) }
  a * b
end

start = Time.now
answer = product_of_coefficients_that_produce_maximum_number_of_primes_for_consecutive_values

puts "The answer is #{answer} and it took #{Time.now-start} seconds."
```

15 lines of hard-core ruby-style code!

Enjoy!

---

**Update**
It seems that `lazy` adds considerable overhead to the performance of the code. So it is not advisable to use it.

Fortunately this works:

```
(0..Float::INFINITY).take_while { |n| (n**2 + a*n + b).prime? }.count
```

My code still runs ~2 times slower than the original (ends in 18 seconds), but it is more reasonable than with `lazy`...

Comment: also, you can `inject` your a*b :)

Comment: I like your code better, but it takes 130 seconds, while the original code takes 10. The prime function is a beauty. I suspect that the count_quadratic_formula_primes method is slow.

Comment: @user2609980 - yes, apparently `lazy` add a lot of overhead... see my update

Comment: user2609980, I'm surprised at the difference in execution times, but I'd pay no heed to that at this stage of your Ruby education.  Uri has covered a wide swath of ground in his answer, acquainting you with typical Ruby coding style, the addition of a method to an existing Ruby class (`prime?`), the use of powerful enumerators `map`, `product`, `permutation`, `any?` and `take_while` from the `Enumerable` module, and `up_to` from the `Integer` class, and Ruby's new `lazy` operator.  He has also nicely explained his reasons for coding it the way he has.  Great answer, Uri.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am indeed very happy with the answer :-).

Comment: Thanks once again :) My Ruby code improved a lot because of your answer and I keep coming back to it.

Comment: @user2609980 - glad to be of service :-)

Comment: Lovely stuff. Can I suggest instead of something like `!(1..10).any? {...}` that the OP use `(1..10).none? {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Rubocop Report

There are a couple of additional offenses against Ruby style guide and conventions that haven't been addressed in the excellent answer.

- Use `# frozen_string_literal: true` top level comment ([why?](https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/02/28/ruby-optimization-with-one-magic-comment/)).
- Insert an empty line after guard clauses: `return false if self < 1`.
- Prefer the zero predicate over 0 check: `self % i == 0` -> `(self % i).zero?`.
- Try to keep the number of lines of each method below 10. `get_amount_of_primes_from_quadratic_formula` has 13 lines.
- Parameter names should be communicative. `a`, `b` should be refactored.
- Do not use `then` for multi-line `if`. `if result.prime? then` -> remove `then`.
- Omit parentheses when the method or def does not define arguments.
- Keep line lengths below 80 characters.